# returning incorrect index using in_array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

The for loop is going thru the $data_statuses array and I expect it to output the value of the **epBwfEntry_update_submitted_epBwfNotify** index, as it exists in the $data (copied the array structure below). I am looping thru that array and stopping once I find a match using the $data_statuses array.

```
$data_statuses = array(
    'epBwfEntry_update_draft'                   =>  'draft',
    'epBwfEntry_create_draft'                   =>  'draft',
    'epBwfEntry_update_draft'                   =>  'draft',
    'epBwfEntry_update_submitted_epBwfNotify'   =>  'pending',
    'epBwfEntry_create_submitted_epBwfNotify'   =>  'pending',
    'epBwfDraft_create_submitted_epBwfNotify'   =>  'pending',
    'epBwfDraft_update_submitted_epBwfNotify'   =>  'pending',
);

foreach($data_statuses as $key => $value)
{
    if (in_array($key, $data))
    {
        print 'data: ' . $key . ': ' . $value . ' => ' . $data[$key]; 
        break;
    }
}

// index epBwfEntry_update_submitted_epBwfNotify exists in the $data array

// outputs: data: epBwfEntry_update_draft: draft =>

// expected output: epBwfEntry_update_submitted_epBwfNotify: pending => submitted

// $data array
Array
(
    [entry_id] => 3356
    [channel_id] => 1
    [autosave_entry_id] => 0
    [field_id_113] => YToxOntzOjE3OiJ0cmlnZ2VyX3JldmlzaW9ucyI7czoxOiIxIjt9
    [field_id_28] => 
    [field_id_103] => 
    [field_id_1] => 
    [field_id_79] => Yes
    [field_id_2] => 
    [field_id_3] => 
    [new_channel] => 1
    [epBwfEntry_update_submitted_epBwfNotify] => submitted
    [schedule_date_status] => no
    [draft_publish_date] => 01/19/2016
    [cp_call] => 1
    [revision_post] => Array
        (
            [entry_id] => 3356
            [channel_id] => 1
            [autosave_entry_id] => 0
            [filter] => 
            [structure__parent_id] => 2927
            [structure__template_id] => 146
            [structure__hidden] => n
            [title] => testtttt
            [structure__uri] => testtttt
            [url_title] => testtttt
            [expiration_date] => 
            [structure__listing_channel] => 0
            [field_id_113] => Array
                (
                    [trigger_revisions] => 1
                )

            [field_id_28] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                )

            [field_id_103] => 
            [field_id_1] => 
            [field_id_79] => Yes
            [field_id_2] => 
            [field_id_3] => 
            [entry_date] => 1452194340
            [new_channel] => 1
            [author] => 112
            [versioning_enabled] => y
            [epBwfEntry_update_submitted_epBwfNotify] => submitted
            [schedule_date_status] => no
            [draft_publish_date] => 01/19/2016
        )

    [options] => 
    [author] => 
)
```

Comment: So is there a question, or at least an explanation, that goes with that code ?

Comment: Also, we have no idea what `$data` is in that code ?

Comment: ....and what is the big Array after the comments for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in_array` checks to see if a *value* exists in the array you are searching. You are not searching for a value but for a key, so you would need (for example...):

```
if (array_key_exists($key, $data)) {
    ...
```

Note that this does not search for keys in values in the array that are arrays themselves but the same applies to `in_array`; both only search the first level of the array.